# Different WP Rest API custom endpoints across different themes

Tags: theme-development, themes, rest-api

I have created a custom theme on Wordpress with custom WP Rest API endpoints. This is how I have set it up.

Theme name: Theme 1

Added below line in functions.php

`require get_parent_theme_file_path( '/inc/myapi-functions.php' );`

And `myapi-functions.php` consists all the custom APIs. Let's take an example endpoint

```
add_action('rest_api_init','lmsRoutes');

function lmsRoutes(){
    register_rest_route( 'abcAPIRoute/v1', 'login', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'loginABCuser'
    ));
}
```

And the loginABCuser is as below

```
function loginBUuser($request){
    //do some wp_rest_get which returns a response 'my dummy text 1'
    $response = // wp_rest_get response;
    return $response;
}
```

The above work perfectly well. I get the response **my dummy text 1** as required.

Now the url in `wp_rest_get` responses keeps changing every time some change happens on the remote API logics. However it is backward compatible in version. Example, I can keep sending the data a v1 url and get the v1 response even if the remote API is in v5 version.

I initially thought using cPanel of the hosting provider I can clone the current theme, make changes in the `myapi-functions.php` and do the necessary testing and development in the cloned theme, and then swap the live theme to cloned theme. Example would be as below (for loginABCuser in cloned theme)

```
function loginBUuser($request){
    //do some wp_rest_get which returns a response 'my dummy text 2'
    $response = // wp_rest_get response;
    return $response;
}
```

I expected the response to be **my dummy text 2** but it still returns **my dummy text 1**

How do I handle this and where am I going wrong?

I even tried changing

```
require get_parent_theme_file_path( '/inc/myapi-functions.php' );
```

to

```
require get_theme_file_path( '/inc/myapi-functions.php' );
```

in `functions.php` but still the same issue.

I can always make the changes and test them in a local environment, but I was wondering if I am limited to do it using cPanel file editor and WP Theme preview, how do I go about it?

And what are the best practices to handle such changes in WP Rest API custom endpoints?

Comment: Does the problem occur only in theme preview or also in the live version? Are you sure this is not a caching issue?

Comment: If you want API endpoints in a theme to work then the theme needs to be active. When previewing a theme it’s only active in that preview window. Regular users and applications are still going to see the active theme.

Comment: @cjbj only in theme preview. I have not tried making the cloned theme live. Should I?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, if that's the case, how do I test newer APIs without impacting live version? Local development is the only scope?

Comment: If it's a new version of the API, then you should be adding it separately to the existing API anyway. You have *both* `register_rest_route( 'abcAPIRoute/v1',...` and `register_rest_route( 'abcAPIRoute/v2',` for example. On top of that you should be using some sort of development. It could be local, or just hosted elsewhere on a different domain/subdomain.

Comment: @JacobPeattie .. In that case, is there any way I can have `myapi-functions.php` file stored in a location outside a theme folder? This way it'll be easy to manage across various themes.. child themes?

Comment: Well, now you're just describing a plugin.